# How to update multiple values in one column using one sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a huge user database and there are around 200 user emails I want to set to an empty value, is there a easy way to remove them all in one query? here is a simple idea of what the table looks like.

(also as there a lots of email, I dont want to looks for all the ids, i only have the emails to work with)

```
 column1 | column2 | customerEmail | column4
1                    email1
2                    email2
3                    email3
```

Here is what i was going for but i received syntax error when using it for multiple values.

```
UPDATE `email-database`
SET customerEmail = ''
WHERE customerEmail = 'test@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com', 'test3@gmail.com';
```

Comment: try with `IN` clause

Comment: if you want to remove all the emails starting with **test** then you can directly use `like` also in your where clause..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

```
UPDATE `email-database`
SET customerEmail = ''
WHERE customerEmail IN ( 'test@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com', 'test3@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this on a test database in phpmyadmin and receive this error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `email-database` WHERE customerEmail IN ( 'test@gmail.com' , 'test2@gmail.com' )' at line 2"

Comment: well that's not from the code I gave. There's no FROM cause in it!

Comment: That's odd, I didn't write a "FROM" in the query, I used the exact syntax provided

Comment: yes sorry, the query was working but for some reason "simulate query" caused the error

Comment: No worries, glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

Note to add `;`  at the end

```
UPDATE `email-database`
SET customerEmail = ''
WHERE customerEmail in ('test@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com', 'test3@gmail.com');
```